# I want to allocate 100GB for a new partition

Tags: 14.04, partitioning, mount, resize

Currently my directory structure is as follows, with an encrypted home drive:

```
Filesystem         Type     1K-blocks    Used Available Use% Mounted on
/dev/sda1          ext4     472429848 6415860 441992896   2% /
none               tmpfs            4       0         4   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
udev               devtmpfs   4024836       4   4024832   1% /dev
tmpfs              tmpfs       808008    1304    806704   1% /run
none               tmpfs         5120       0      5120   0% /run/lock
none               tmpfs      4040024     468   4039556   1% /run/shm
none               tmpfs       102400      32    102368   1% /run/user
/home/jay/.Private ecryptfs 472429848 6415860 441992896   2% /home/jay


Disk /dev/sda: 500.1 GB, 500107862016 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 60801 cylinders, total 976773168 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x000237eb

   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sda1   *        2048   960190463   480094208   83  Linux
/dev/sda2       960192510   976771071     8289281    5  Extended
Partition 2 does not start on physical sector boundary.
/dev/sda5       960192512   976771071     8289280   82  Linux swap / Solaris
```

What I would like is to add a 100GB allocation to /mysql. Is this possible?

Comment: You got a physical sector boundary on /dev/sda2. fix that before going further.

Comment: I'm not sure what that means.

Comment: It means the Partition is not perfectly aligned. it may affect read/write IO rates.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it appears that you can shrink the partition /dev/sda1 to make a 100GB partition for `/mysql`.  There are many answers on here that will instruct you how to *shrink partitions with gparted*.

You shouldn't need to change your `/etc/fstab' as long as your system partion is still the first partition on the disk.

So your only extra task is how you give the new partition to mysql.

To fix the mis-alignment problem, from the Live boot, in `gparted`, you just delete the swap partition, then delete the extended partition, then add them back.